# How to create a recursive separator?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to learn recursion and am separating odd and even values in two lists and merging them to another list as below:

Code:

```
def separateNumbers(L):
    evenList = []
    oddList = []
    main = []
    if len(L)==0:
        return L
    if L[0] % 2 == 0:
        evenList.append(L[0])
        separateNumbers(L[1:])
    if L[0] % 2 == 1:
        oddList.append(L[0])
        separateNumbers(L[1:])
    main.append(evenList)
    main.append(oddList)
    return main

inputList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
L = separateNumbers(inputList)
print(L)
```

Input:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Output:

```
[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
```

The even and odd arrays reset everytime the recursive function is called, how can I fix this?

Tried with inner function:

```
def separateNumbers(L):
    evenList = []
    oddList = []
    main = []
    def inner(L):
        if len(L)==0:
            return L
        if L[0] % 2 == 0:
            evenList.append(L[0])
            inner(L[1:])
        if L[0] % 2 == 1:
            oddList.append(L[0])
            inner(L[1:])
        main.append(evenList)
        main.append(oddList)
        return main
    a = inner(L)
    return a
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 
10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: Make a nested function to do the actual recursion

Comment: I tried the inner function but did not get the answer, I'm showing the change in original post. Something about recursion that I don't understand

Comment: Inner should never call `main.append(oddList)`. If you want to understand your code, Trace through it by hand

Comment: I usually debug and trace my code but with recursion even that does not help understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested function. try:

```py
def separate_numbers(lst):
    if not lst: # empty list
        return [], []
    odd, even = separate_numbers(lst[1:]) # recursion call
    if lst[0] % 2: # if the first item is odd
        return [lst[0], *odd], even
    else: # if even
        return odd, [lst[0], *even]

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(separate_numbers(lst)) # ([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

The function calls itself using the tail part of the input list, receiving two lists: `odd` for odd numbers and `even` for even numbers. Then it returns those lists, after attaching the head element `lst[0]` to one of the lists.